# Jsf life cycle - render response after validation failure

Tags: jsf

I'm hoping BalusC or one of you JSF experts can help me understand the finer points of the JSF life cycle, particularly rendering.

What I'm struggling to understand is that during render response, values are obtained from the model and displayed to the user. Now, if there were validation errors, the model is not updated, so the renderer must have to show the user the invalid value from the component tree. That's all well and good but how does the renderer determine whether to read from the model, or read from the component tree? If it's from the component tree, does that mean if a request passes validation and an event handler updates model values just prior to rendering, will those values be reflected to the user?

I've read lots about the jsf life cycle but nothing I've found goes into it deeply enough to answer my questions. I want to understand precisely how this stuff works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

During the apply request values phase, all request parameters are set as submitted value on `UIInput` by `setSubmittedValue()`.

During the validations phase, only and only if the value is valid, the submitted value is set to `null` and the converted and validated value is set on `UIInput` by `setValue()`. So if the value is not valid, then the submitted value won't be set to `null`.

During the update model values phase, the model value is updated with that value.

During the render response phase, the `UIInput` renderer first checks if `getSubmittedValue()` doesn't return `null`. If it doesn't (so, validation has failed), then display it. Otherwise just display the model value.