# Which class contains the rendering logic of submitted value vs model value?

Tags: jsf, rendering, jsf-1.2

I am a bit confused about `submittedValue` and `value` in JSF. Which value is rendered when there is a converter/validation error?

[Jsf life cycle - render response after validation failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10965283/jsf-life-cycle-render-response-after-validation-failure/10965564#10965564)

From BalusC's answer in the above question I could find the answer. However, I would like to know in which class this rendering logic is present that the model value is rendered when submitted value is null. Which class is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *I would like to know in which class this rendering logic is present that the model value is rendered when submitted value is null*

You didn't tell anywhere about the JSF implementation being used. In this answer I'll assume that it's Mojarra. In that case, it's done in [`HtmlBasicRenderer#getCurrentValue()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax.faces/jsf-impl/1.2_15/com/sun/faces/renderkit/html_basic/HtmlBasicRenderer.java#HtmlBasicRenderer.getCurrentValue%28com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.FacesContext,com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.UIComponent%29). Here's an extract of relevance coming from Mojarra 1.2_15.

```
275    protected String getCurrentValue(FacesContext context,
276                                     UIComponent component) {
277
278        if (component instanceof UIInput) {
279            Object submittedValue = ((UIInput) component).getSubmittedValue();
280            if (submittedValue != null) {
281                // may not be a String...
282                return submittedValue.toString();
283            }
284        }
285
286        String currentValue = null;
287        Object currentObj = getValue(component);
288        if (currentObj != null) {
289            currentValue = getFormattedValue(context, component, currentObj);
290        }
291        return currentValue;
292
293    }
```

Code speaks for itself. If the component is an instance of `UIInput`, then get its submitted value. If it's not `null`, then return it. Else just proceed returning the model value the usual way.

MyFaces uses a similar approach.

Comment: Thanks BalusC, your support is very helpful.